# rails - how to get search display blank when search field is blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am using metasearch.  I want to search for friends using email.

In my users controller:

```
def index
 @search = User.search(params[:search])
 @users = @search.all
end
```

In my view:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>

<div class="prepend-top field">
  <%= f.label("Primary email address") %></br>    
  <%= f.text_field(:email_matches) %>
</div> 

<div class="prepend-top field">
  <%= f.label("School email address") %></br>    
  <%= f.text_field(:school_email_matches) %>
</div> 

<div>
 <ul>
   <% if params[:search].blank? %>
     Your search results here.
   <% else %>
     <% @users.each do |user| %>
       <li class="box round">
         <%= user.name %></br>
       </li>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The way it is now, the results are displayed on an adjacent column on the same page.  I am trying to have it so that if the search form is blank then it returns a blank search.

Problems:

1. When I go to the page initially, the search results side is blank and does say "Your search results here".  But, when I just click on the search button without putting anything in the search fields, it returns a list of all the users on the search result column.  How do I make it so that a blank search form truly returns a blank page?
2. How do I go about making it so that it shows "No results for your search criteria"? if there are no matches for the particular search?

Thanks.

Comment: also, there is an <% end %> missing at to close the form in your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your problem is happening because when you search for an empty string, your search function returns all your users.

So, in your controller, you could do:

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
      empty_search = params[:search].keep_if {|k, val| !val.blank?}.empty?
    else
      empty_search = true
    end

    if empty_search
     # no search was submitted, or search params are all blank
     @search = ""
     @users = []

    else
     # a search was submitted
     @search = User.search(params[:search])
     @users = @search.all
    end
  end
```

(not sure about the exact terminology for the condition, but basically, if you're passing an empty string or nothing, you should run the 'else' piece of the code).

In the view, you could do:

```
   <% if @search.blank? %>
     Your search results here.
   <% else %>
     <% if @users.blank? %>
       No results for you
     <% else %>
       <ul>
       <% @users.each do |user| %>
         <li class="box round">
           <%= user.name %></br>
         </li>
       <% end %>
       </ul>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
```

Would that work?

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Part 2 of my question is resolved.  Unfortunately, it still displays all the users when I click the "seach" button with nothing in the search fields.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of -- params[:search] && !params[:search].blank? --?  I thought it reads : "regardless of if the params of search is blank or not"?

Comment: i made a few changes in the code. let me know if if works for you. basically, you want to find if a search was submitted with real params. If so, you can run the search. If not, you return an empty array as a result.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  That worked.  I made two changes to it.  The first change is to the controller.  I added the '@search = User.search(params[:search])' in place of the '@search = ""' because it would bring me to the user signup page if I just click on search.  The second change was in the view.  I changed the '@search.blank?' to 'params[:search].blank?' because the result was the same as '@user.blank?'.  Not sure why, but this works perfectly now.  Thank you!

Comment: can you explain this line of code? :empty_search = params[:search].keep_if {|k, val| !val.blank?}.empty?